# How to get a single doc info from firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

```
function AccountPage() {

    const [{ patients, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
    
    var therapist = '';

    db.collection('therapists').doc(user.uid).get().then((snapshot) => {
        therapist = snapshot.data()
        console.log(therapist)
      })

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(therapist)
        var allService = therapist.service.service[0].label
    
        for (let i = 1; i < therapist.service.service.length; i++) {
            allService += ', ' + therapist.service.service[i].label;
        }
    
        var allLanguages = therapist.language.language[0].label
    
        for (let i = 1; i < therapist.language.language.length; i++) {
            allLanguages += ', ' + therapist.language.language[i].label;
        }
    }, [])
```

I'm trying to read a document in the firebase collection. I can read it and display to console, but for some reason I am not able to save the data. If I try to use therapist variable later in the code, it is undefined. I tried using useState, but it does the same thing, where therapist is undefined. I really don't get it.

[image]

Tried using useState, with or without therapist in UseEffect, without useEffect

Comment: Do `service.service[i]` and `language.language[i]` exist in the document itself or are they in subcollections of the main document called `service` and `language`?

Answer (score 1):

Something to keep in mind with React components is that their render methods are to be considered pure, synchronous functions. The ***entire*** body of a React function component ***is*** the render "method". Each time `AccountPage` is rendered is declares `therapist = ""`, and then an ***unintentional*** side-effect to collect the firebase document is kicked off. The `useEffect` hook runs after the component has rendered  and tries to read properties of the empty string value that is `therapist` and throws the error.

`therapist` should be part of the React state so that it can be updated and trigger a rerender with the fetched data. The firebase document should be fetched as an ***intentional*** side-effect via a `useEffect` hook.

```
function AccountPage() {
  const [{ patients, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
    
  const [therapist, setTherapist] = React.useState();

  // Fetch therapists document for specific user
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user.uid) {
      db.collection('therapists').doc(user.uid).get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          setTherapist(snapshot.data());
        });
    }
  }, [user]);

  // Compute services and languages when therapist state updates
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(therapist);

    const allService = therapist?.service?.service
      .map(({ label }) => label)
      .join(", ");
    const allLanguages = therapist?.language?.language
      .map(({ label }) => label)
      .join(", ");

    ...

  }, [therapist]);

  ...
```